# How do I add a bullet point before a line of text in ZPL on a Zebra ZD500R?

Tags: unicode, utf, zpl

My current line of text for the line on the label is:

part4c = "^FWI,0^FB1160,8,0,L^FO45,1185^CF0,33^FH^FD_0xE2_0x80_0xA2 ONLY programming starting with S, N, P, or H (including claiming CME).^FS"

The current output is:

^FWI,0^FB1160,8,0,L^FO45,1185^CF0,33^FH^FD_0xE2_0x80_0xA2 ONLY programming starting with S, N, P, or H (including claiming CME).^FS

I believe I'll need to include some commands to account for the text after the utf code but I'm not sure what

I've tried using other examples on StackOverlfow but all the examples only include foreign languages or single UTF codes.